# location with OFF internet connection

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get current exact user's location coordinates, and update the location when the user moving without internet connection in android.
which says "Common sources of location information include `Global Positioning System (GPS)` using `GPS-PROVIDER`
and location inferred from network signals such as `IP address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs using 'NETWORK-PROVIDER'`.
It is well known that the `GPS` doesn't need internet connection to get the location.

So the question is what about the network provider??
Can I use network provider when internet connection is **OFF** ? if not ? **why** !!
I think it can work without internet because it Depends on `GSM/CDMA` cells so it will get the location by the Signals connect with cell tower, I hope I'm thinking right.

By the way I have not used the google location Apis (client & server) because I read more than once that it needs an Internet connection,
that's why I'm using now Android APIs `locationManager()`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, google's location API's makes the most out of the network connection when it comes to location.

Either way, from Android developers: "The Google Play services location APIs are preferred over the Android framework location APIs (android.location) as a way of adding location awareness to your app. If you are currently using the Android framework location APIs, you are strongly encouraged to switch to the Google Play services location APIs as soon as possible."

Follow this link for more info:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: You did not understand my question well, i think Google Play services location APIs works with internet, and this is what I do not want

Comment: I did, my answer if for the practical aspect. Your best option for now is to use Google API and its  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation().
As for, getting the location by the Signals connect with cell tower, the current Android API is not that sophisticated.
If it was, they wouldn't recommend you to use Google's location service...

Comment: thank you for reply, but can i use Google API to get location without internet?  this is what confusing me because i don't want any internet connection in my project

Comment: i saw this [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/) using Google API, it need internet to work

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there is no offline mechanism to retrieve user location except GPS.